# cannot scroll a custom view

Tags: android, scroll

I have a view and I want to scroll it, however nothing happens, no scroll bars are visible even when I use `android:scrollbars= vertical` please help

```
 <view
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/etContentJoke"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toplayout"
    class="ie.myjokes.LineEditText"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:capitalize="sentences"
    android:fadingEdge="vertical"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="22sp" >

    <requestFocus />
</view>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping it in a scrollview should work

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    <view
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/etContentJoke"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toplayout"
        class="ie.myjokes.LineEditText"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:capitalize="sentences"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="22sp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </view>
</ScrollView >
```

more everything in your view into the scrollview that is scrollable, such as android:scrollbars

Answer (score 0):

A simple `View` is not scrollable. You need to wrap it in a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).